# If $g^{-1} \circ f \circ g$ is $C^\infty$ whenever $f$ is $C^\infty$, must $g$ be $C^\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Suppose that $g$ is a bijection on the real line, and $g^{-1} \circ f \circ g$ is a $C^\infty$ function whenever $f$ is $C^\infty$.  It seems howlingly obvious that this can only happen if $g$ is itself $C^\infty$.  But I can't figure out how to prove it.

Can you help me, Internets?

(Context: I want to show that in a manifold of dimension at least 2, the facts about which unparameterized curves are smooth suffice to determine the differential structure.  I think I can sort of see how to prove this provided I can rely on the claim above, but that's where I'm stuck.  However, if anyone here knows of a proof of the geometric claim, pointers would be most welcome.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a result due to Floris Takens:

> Let $\Phi \colon M_1 \to M_2$ be a bijection between two smooth $n$-manifolds such that $\lambda \colon M_2 \to M_2$ is a diffeomorphism iff $\Phi^{-1} \circ \lambda \circ \Phi$ is a diffeomorphism.  Then $\Phi$ is a diffeomorphism.

It can be found in *Characterization of a differentiable structure by its group of diffeomorphisms* (Math Reviews number: MR552032).  I remember that I found an online version of it (but don't remember where off the top of my head, probably via MathSciNet).  I don't have it in front of me, but I do recall that the argument was fairly involved.  (I found it for a fairly similar reason: I wanted to show that the only Frölicher space with endomorphism monoid $C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ was $\mathbb{R}$ itself, this is Proposition 8.4 of [Comparative Smootheology](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/Research/Preprints/smthcat.html).)

---

**Update**: After reading the comments, I realised that the quoted theorem is not quite what is wanted.  Actually, what you need is Proposition 8.4 of [Comparative Smootheology](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/Research/Preprints/smthcat.html), which uses Takens' result at the key stage but nonetheless is about a page long in the proving.  The result in the paper is:

> The only Frölicher structures on $\mathbb{R}$ whose endomorphism monoid contains $C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ are the standard, the discrete, and the indiscrete structures.  In particular, the only Frölicher structure on $\mathbb{R}$ whose endomorphism monoid is precisely $C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is the standard structure.

You can almost replace "Frölicher structure" by "smooth structure" in the above, except that there's no such thing as the "indiscrete smooth structure".  The *discrete* smooth/Frölicher structure on $\mathbb{R}$ views $\mathbb{R}$ as a load of disjoint points: a zero-dimensional manifold.  This is characterised by the fact that the only smooth functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_{disc}$ are the constant functions (here the unadorned $\mathbb{R}$ is the usual manifold $\mathbb{R}$).  The indiscrete structure is the opposite: the only smooth functions $\mathbb{R}_{indisc} \to \mathbb{R}$ are the constant functions.  So we could rephrase the above result as:

> The only smooth structures on $\mathbb{R}$ whose endomorphism monoid contains $C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ are the standard and the discrete structures.  In particular, the only smooth structure on $\mathbb{R}$ whose endomorphism monoid is precisely $C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is the standard structure.

Let us connect that to your question.  You ask:

> If $g \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a bijection such that $g^{-1} \circ f \circ g$ is $C^\infty$ whenever $f$ is $C^\infty$, must $g$ be $C^\infty$?

First, we can use $g$ to put a smooth structure on $\mathbb{R}$ by post-composing $g$ with charts (or pre-composing with $g^{-1}$ if your charts go *from* your manifold).  Let us write this as $\mathbb{R}_g$.  For clarity, let us write $\mathbb{R}_s$ for the standard smooth structure on $\mathbb{R}$.  Then $g \colon \mathbb{R}_s \to \mathbb{R}_g$ is a diffeomorphism, by construction.  Given a smooth function $f \colon \mathbb{R}_s \to \mathbb{R}_s$ we get a smooth function $f_g \colon \mathbb{R}_g \to \mathbb{R}_g$ by $g \circ f \circ g^{-1}$.  Conversely, given a smooth function $h \colon \mathbb{R}_g \to \mathbb{R}_g$, $g^{-1} \circ h \circ g$ is smooth on $\mathbb{R}_s$ and thus is $C^\infty$.  Hence the endomorphism monoid of $\mathbb{R}_g$, $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}_g,\mathbb{R}_g)$, is $g C^\infty(\mathbb{R}_s,\mathbb{R}_s) g^{-1}$.

The condition imposed is that $g^{-1} \circ f \circ g \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ for all $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$.  The $\mathbb{R}$s here are $\mathbb{R}_s$ in our notation.  Translated into a single statement (rather than one for each $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, this is: $g^{-1} C^\infty(\mathbb{R}_s,\mathbb{R}_s) g \subseteq C^\infty(\mathbb{R}_s,\mathbb{R}_s)$.  Now here's the sneaky bit; the inclusion here is going the wrong way.  So we simply apply $g \circ  - \circ g^{-1}$ to both sides to get $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}_s,\mathbb{R}_s) \subseteq g C^\infty(\mathbb{R}_s,\mathbb{R}_s) g^{-1}$.

Now we apply my result to deduce that $\mathbb{R}_g$ must be either the discrete smooth structure (which it isn't) or the standard one: $\mathbb{R}_g = \mathbb{R}_s$.  But then $g$ is a diffeomorphism $\mathbb{R}_s \to \mathbb{R}_g = \mathbb{R}_s$ and hence is $C^\infty$.

Comment: Takens's paper is online through Springer at http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02588337 (not linked form MathSciNet yet)

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need - thanks so much.  However, I just noticed that Takens's result has an 'iff' in the hypothesis where my claim just has the left to right direction.  Is this easy to fix, do you think?

Comment: @Cian: iff implies if, so if there exists a proof for iff, you're all set.

Comment: @Ben: "iff implies if" means here that part of the hypothesis is stronger.

Comment: @Jonas: Right.  The hypothesis is more specific, so the theorem is weaker.  oops.

Comment: @Ben, @Jonas, @Cian: good comments.  My original answer was left in haste, I've expanded it now.

Comment: @Andrew: thanks very much, this is incredibly helpful and I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Cian: glad it helped.  I happen to be revising that paper at the moment so it was uppermost in my mind and thus quite straightforward to work out the details.

Comment: @Andrew: I've been pursuing this inquiry in another MSE question - 26954.  There, I've been struggling to see how your result plays out in the case of $g(x)=x^3$.  Since this is not a diffeomorphism, there must be some smooth $f$ such that $g^{-1}\circ f \circ g$, i.e. $(f(x^3))^{1/3}$, is not smooth.  Right?  But I have not found an example, and others were suggesting that there is no such $f$.

Comment: @Cian: I suspect I'm missing something, but doesn't $f(x) = 1 + x$ work?  It's easier to see if we reverse $g$ and $g^{-1}$ since we get $(1 + x^{1/3})^3 = 1 + 3 x^{1/3} + 3 x^{2/3} + x^3$ which isn't smooth at $x = 0$.

Comment: (For my own convenience, here's a link to that other question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/26954/2907)